# Android UI issue when using nested layouts

Tags: android, android-layout

I have issues with rendering the User Interface when using nested layouts, especially nested scroll views. The outermost container is the **ScrollView** and then a 2nd layout, **ConstraintLayout** and finally a **HorizontalScrollView**.

But, by using the above set of nested viewgroups, some (or most) of the views are not displaying in some mobiles (all android 5.0+).

Now, each of them is required for my app. The code is as follows:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:context="com.natramizh.trademanagement.ReportPurchaseRegisterActivity">

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:elevation="3dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/guidelineH47P" />

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/fragment_agent_detail_header"
            android:name="com.natramizh.trademanagement.AgentDetailHeaderFragment"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_agent_detail_header" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvReportDate"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="@string/lblReportDate"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline40P"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/fragment_agent_detail_header" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtDate"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="date"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/tvReportDate"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline40P"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/tvReportDate"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="27dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnSubmit"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="@string/btnSubmit"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtDate" />

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:id="@+id/productConsolidateHScrollView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/btnSubmit">

            <android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
                android:id="@+id/gridPurchaseRegister"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnSubmit">

            </android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>
        </HorizontalScrollView>


        <android.support.constraint.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/guideline40P"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.40" />

        <android.support.constraint.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/guidelineH47P"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.47" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

The output I get looks like this:

[report purchase register screen issue - image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0cSO3.png)

As you can see from the above linked image, the button is totally invisible. And all the below views are also invisible even when running on real device.

Now, all I need is a solution to my problem. Point out what mistake I did or does it just need a few tweaks. And is this the right way to get a fully scrollable screen.

NOTE: The gridlayout will be added dynamically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make your scrollview like this set `android:fillViewport` property of your Scroll view

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:fillViewport="true">

  // add here your all controls

</ScrollView >
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. But even after changing what you have mentioned, the problem still exists!

Comment: @Leo make your  android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"

Comment: Your answer was right. Earlier I used fillViewPort=true and layout_height=wrap_content for ScrollView element, but now I changed it to fillViewPort=true and layout_height=match_parent and it works!